# rotar elementos de un array con una posicion fija

Tags: php

tengo este array

```
$a = Array("a","b","c","d");
```

quiero que me rote b ,c , d. Es decir, que B se coloque en donde d y se bajen la posición.

Ejemplo:

```
abcd
acdb
adbc
```

llevo de momento.

```
$a = Array("a","b","c","d");
print_r($a);
$num = count($a)-1;

for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
    for($i = $num; $i>=1;$i--){
        if($i>1){
            $aux = $a[$i-1];
            $a[$i-1] = $a[$i];
            print_r($a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Juega con los indices y las posiciones.

Comment: No es este caso pero si que parecido.

Comment: ¿Es decir que si la distancia entre ellos es de 2 posiciones, que todos se muevan 2 posiciones a la derecha? ¿Qué es lo constante? ¿Siempre son 2 posiciones?

Comment: en realidad se deberia mover una a la izquierda excepto la que este al lado de a, que debe colocarse al final.

Comment: A ver si he comprendido bien: quieres que d se mueva a la posición de b y "empujar" los elementos atrás una posición, ¿o ese es el comportamiento que ocurre solo en el caso particular de 4 elementos?

Comment: Sería b ponerla al final y empujar al resto

Comment: pero de hecho estás moviento a la izquierda 2 veces. Insisto: ¿qué es constante de todo el problema y qué no?

Comment: A ver si yo me entero, poner el segundo elemento al final y empujar al resto? Es correcto?

Comment: @Borja: lee [¿Cómo funcionan las `@respuestas` en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83) para entender bien cómo responder a una persona en concreto. Si no, esto es un jaleo. Además, en lugar de dar información en los comentarios, dale a [edit] y añádela en la pregunta.

Comment: Exacto es así @Xerif. Como ejemplo es : ABCD, ACDB y así.

Comment: Constante es A, bcd tiene que cambiar @fedorqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aun que la solución del compañero funciona creo que seria mucho más óptimo y simple hacerlo de la siguiente manera sin utilizar bucles anidados que siempre son una mala idea.

```
<?php 
$a = Array("a","b","c","d");

// extraemos el elemento
$corte = array_splice ( $a, 1, 1 );

// añadimos el elemento al final
array_push ( $a, $corte[0] );

print_r ( $a );
// Array ( [0] => a [1] => c [2] => d [3] => b )
```

Answer (score 1):

Reordenando un poco tu codigo asi te deberia valer.

```
$a = Array("a","b","c","d");
print_r($a);
$num = count($a);

for($i=1;$i<$num-1;$i++){
        $aux = $a[1];
        for($j=1;$j<$num-1;$j++){
            $a[$j] = $a[$j+1];
        }
        $a[$num-1] = $aux;
        print_r($a);
}
```

Salida:

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [0] => a                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [1] => b                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [2] => c                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [3] => d                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [0] => a                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [1] => c                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [2] => d                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [3] => b                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [0] => a                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [1] => d                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [2] => b                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [3] => c                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
)
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias.

Comment: me parece poco eficiente esta opción.